# Compare two arrays and remove equal objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a list of words and a list of words specific for an exercise. Users can move words between each list. But there should not be any word duplicates. It works fine until I need to re-fetch the data after saving to an SQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to remove from `array2` anything that is present in `array1`, you can:

```
[array2 removeObjectsInArray:array1];
```